# Mongodb prevent duplicate value entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I'm making a basic website which pulls user information and posts them to database. What I'm having problem achieving is preventing the user from signing up if they've signed up before.

I've tried, `createIndex(unique:true)` `find` `ensureIndex(unique:true)` methods but with no success. Maybe I've messed up the syntax? I either get `Promise { <pending> }` as return value or the whole document itself with numerous unrelated information.

**MY .JS FILE**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/ibs';
var async = require('async');
var session = require('express-session');
var code = require('./verificationCode');


router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {



    router.post('/form', function (req, res) {

        var name = req.body.name;
        var surname = req.body.surname;
        var phone = req.body.phone;
        var email = req.body.email;
        // var address = req.body.adress;
        var verCode = code.code();
        mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {

            person = {
                Name: req.body.name,
                Surname: surname,
                Phone: phone,
                Email: email,
                // Adress: address,
                verCode: verCode
            }


            db.collection('user').insert(person);



            res.redirect('/congratulations');
        });
    });

    res.render('information');


});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why is your POST handler inside your GET handler?

Answer (score 0):

The method that I use is a simple if() statement to check to see if someone with that name/username is already inserted

```
(async function addUser() {      
  let client;
       try {
           client = await MongoClient.connect(url);

           const db = client.db(dbName);
           const col = db.collection('users');
           const userFromDB = await col.findOne({ //the user you will be inserting});
           if (userFromDB) {
              // dont insert user
           } else {
              // insert user
           }
       } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
       }
}());
```

If userFromDB is true then if found one and you dont want to insert. If it is false then you do want to insert.